# How do I correctly create a reference to a Unity object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and Unity and am having trouble finding a clear answer to my problem.

I am trying to create a simple `TextMeshProUGUI` text log buffer in a panel.  The buffer itself works fine until I try to access it from another class - I believe because I am not creating the reference to the panel correctly.

Here is my code for the `TextMeshProUGUI` object collector:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TextLogControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textPrefab;  // Unity prefab 

    public  List<TextMeshProUGUI> textItems = new List<TextMeshProUGUI>();

    [SerializeField]
    public int maxItems = 100;


    public void LogText(string newTextString, Color newColor)
    {

    Instantiate(textPrefab, transform);

        textPrefab.text = newTextString;

        if (textItems.Count >= maxItems)
        {
            textItems.RemoveAt(0); // I should probably be destroying something, but that's another question
        }

        textPrefab.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        textItems.Add(textPrefab);
    }

    // The above function works correctly if I write a test function within this same class

}
```

Here is the code for the class that is trying to access the `LogText()` function:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class World : MonoBehaviour
{
    Color defaultColor = Color.black;

    public TextLogControl textLog; 


    public void Init()
    {
        // I need to create a reference here somewhere, but nothing I am trying is working

        textLog.LogText("Welcome - you made it!", defaultColor);

    }
}
```

I am putting the `TextLogControl` script on the Unity `GameObject` that is holding the `TMP` objects, and that works on its own.

I thought that I was creating a reference to the holder `GameObject` by dragging it onto my World object in Unity as below, but I am still getting an NRE when I call `World.Init()`, which means that I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what.

I thought this would create the reference that is not being created

[image: I thought this would create the reference that is not being created]

Edit: The error I'm receiving is

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When trying to run `World.Init()` - specifically, `textLog` is null, even though I have got it dragged onto the appropriate spot in Unity (I believe).

Comment: instantiate at `transform.position` not transform

Comment: also post that the error that you are facing

Comment: 'transform' is doing what I need it to do - 'transform.position' gives me a pre-compile error telling me it cannot convert from UnityEngine.Vector3 to UnityEngine.Transform.

Is there a benefit to using 'transform.position' over 'transform'?

Comment: transform.position is a vector3 position. Transform is parent of instantiated object.Check this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html Also post error

Comment: Thanks - sorry, first question!  I've edited to include the error message.

Comment: I was trying to set the parent of the instantiated object.  When I didn't have that line, it was cloning each prefab as a new object outside of the container that I wanted them to live in.

Comment: and check that your list is filled but not empty

Comment: I will add a check, thank you - my big concern right now is the NRE, but I know there are a lot of other things I should be doing :P

Comment: You declare `textLog` in your `World` class but that variable is going to be null until you find the instance of the text log in the scene and assign it to the variable. I don't program in unity but there should be something that finds components in your scene by tag. Something like `textLog = FindByTag<TextLog>("tag")`

Comment: Apparently it's this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

Comment: It's possible that, due to the order in which the components are created in Play mode, your `textLog` hasn't yet been assigned by the engine when `.Init()` is called. Remember that, when you run the game, everything has to be created and initialized, and that happens in a specific sequence. Also, consider using the default `Start()` method for your initialization rather than rolling your own.

Comment: I will try doing FindByTag - at this point, though, I've been stuck for so long that I'm thinking about just ripping the whole idea of the log out and just creating a reusable modal dialog window.

Answer (score 2):

As this is so long for comment,
A null reference means that it is trying to access something that doesn't exist. You either forgot to drag something in the editor, or you are a step ahead and have something un-commented that should still be commented. Your code is using something that isn't there. I recommend you to add this piece of  code to your files to check either the error is coming from NullRefrence of class or the else code.

```
    TextMeshProUGUIs = textPrefab.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    if (TextMeshProUGUIs == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No TextMeshProUGUI component found.");  
    }
```

Comment: What you pasted doesn't compile. The object that is null is textLog - but I have created the reference in Unity and don't understand why it is null.